# Process Start to open image file in resources folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a C# program that I need to embed an image into or perhaps better stated make the exe file portable such that the image will open on any computer and I need the image to open up in the default picture viewer (not a form PictureBox).  I do have the image in the resource folder with 'Embed Resource'

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.MyImage;
```

I realize the above code is invalid, but I am just a coding hobbyist, so I don't know everything.  If I could get a little push in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Note that there is no Resources folder in a deployed app; and if you create one, your app may not have access to it when deployed.  [Process.Start Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick for you but If you want a Default Image Viewer to open a picture, you need to store that image to somewhere on your disk, thus the Image Viewer could find and open your picture.

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.MyImage);
bitmap.Save("YourImageLocation");
Process.Start("YourIamgeLocation");
```

Comment: The above suggestion did work, I saved the image to a common location: bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\temp.jpg").  It was the part about needing to save it first that had me hung up.